# swiftでメニューを作りたい

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

iPhone(swift)で以下のようなメニューを作りたいと思っています。

[image: 作りたいメニュー]

UITableviewで作れそうな感じですが、
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
などを用いて作るのは非常に大変そうで、もっと簡単に作ることはできないかと思っています。
またこのメニューの中にON/OFFの切り替えスイッチ以外にも、直接値を入力できるフィールドを設置できないかとも思っています。

もし簡単に作ることができるのならご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboard上で、 **Tableの属性を「Static Cells」** にすれば、セル上の編集をすべてStoryboardで行えます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

セル上に配置したインスタンスと、View Controllerに宣言した`@outlet`インスタンスを、直接接続できます。

注意点は、Static Cellsの設定をするには、`UITableViewController`のサブクラスが必要な点です。`UIViewController`のサブクラスに`UITableView`インスタンスを設置しては、Static Cellsにすることはできません。

Comment: UITableViewController上では色々な制約がありまして、単純なログインフォームでさえStatic Cellsで作成できません。UITableViewController上で調整して作った方がいいのか、ViewController上でDynamicで作った方がいいのかご存知であれば御指南いただけると幸いです。

Comment: お話しの内容は、新規に質問をたてるに値するものと感じられます。とくに「色々な制約がありまして、」のところを、詳細に説明なさる必要があろうかと思います。Dynamic Cellの利用だと、数多くUITableViewCellのサブクラスを作成する必要があるのではないかと思います。

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。新規に質問を立てます。